# Doubt regarding limit of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If $g (x,y)=\frac {xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $ at $(x,y)\neq (0,0) $ and $0$ at $(x,y)=(0,0) $ then prove that its not differentiable at $(0,0) $ without using partial derivatives. So I used the definition of differentiability. To be differentiable there has to be a definite value of $\frac {|g (x,y)-g (0,0) |}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}} $ and this should be equal to value at $0,0$ . So we need to find $\lim_{x,y\to 0,0} \frac {|xy|}{x^2+y^2 }$. But this function seems to be having no limit using the path $y=mx $ . Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if there is some vector $L$ such that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|g(x,y) - g(0,0) - L\cdot (x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$. So to show that it is not differentiable means to show that there is no such vector $L$, i.e. that the limit does not exist (or is infinite, which is similar) for any value of $L$. The limit in your case simplifies to $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|xy - L\cdot (x,y)|}{x^2+y^2}$. With some fiddling, you could probably show that there is no $L$ that makes the limit exist for all possible approaches.

Note, however, that in this case, it is easier to show that $g$ is not continuous, so it can't be differentiable. This can be done by approaching along the lines $y=mx$, as you suggested.